# Erro em arquivo html

Tags: javascript, html

Eu estou tentando fazer um formulario em html em que receba idade nome e sexo de uma pessoa e faça comparações para ver se a idade passada é maior que a idade que está atual mente no textbox idademaisvelha (para mulher) e idademaisvelho (para homem), caso seja, irá passar a idade que foi passada no textbox para um desses textbox dependendo do sexo da pessoa, não entendo mt de html, javascript nem css;

Código abaixo:

```
<html>
<script>
function execucoes()
{

    if(form1.nome.value == "" && form1.idade.value == "" && form1.sexo[0].checked == false && form1.sexo[1].checked == false)
    {
    {alert("Preencha todos os campos!");}
    }
    else
    {
        if(parseInt(form1.idademaisvelho.value) < parseInt(form1.idade.value) || parseInt(form1.idademaisvelha.value) < parseInt(form1.idade.value))
        {
            if(form1.sexo[0].checked == true)
            {
            form1.nomemaisvelho.value = form1.nome.value;
            form1.idademaisvelho.value = form1.idade.value;
            }
            else
            {
            form1.nomemaisvelha.value = form1.nome.value;
            form1.idademaisvelha.value = form1.idade.value;
            }   
        }
    }
}
</script>
<body>
<form name = "form1">
Digite o seu nome: <input type = text name = "nome" value = "">
<br><br>
Sexo: Masculino<input type = radio name = "sexo" value = "">
      Feminino<input type = radio name = "sexo" value = "">
<br><br>
Digite a sua idade: <input type = text name = "idade" value = "0">
                    <input type = button name = "classificar" onclick = "execucoes()" value = "Classificar">
<br><br>
Nome do Homem mais velho: <input type = text name = "nomemaisvelho" value = "" disabled>
Idade do Homem mais velho: <input type = text name = "idademaisvelho" value = "" disabled>
<br><br>
Nome da Mulher mais velha: <input type = text name = "nomemaisvelha" value = "" disabled>
Idade da Mulher mais velha: <input type = text name = "idademaisvelha" value = "" disabled>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode colar este código que vai funcionar ;)

```
<html>
<script>
function execucoes() {
    var form = document.forms[0];
    var idade = form.querySelector('input[name="idade"]');
    var nome = form.querySelector('input[name="nome"]');
    var sexo1 = form.sexo[0];
    var sexo2 = form.sexo[1];
    var nomeMaisVelho = form.querySelector('input[name="nomemaisvelho"]');
    var nomeMaisVelha = form.querySelector('input[name="nomemaisvelha"]');
    var idadeMaisVelho = form.querySelector('input[name="idademaisvelho"]');
    var idadeMaisVelha = form.querySelector('input[name="idademaisvelha"]');
    if(nome.value == "" && idade.value == "" && sexo1.checked == false && sexo2.checked == false) {
        alert("Preencha todos os campos!");
    } else if(idadeMaisVelho.value < idade.value && sexo1.checked == true || idadeMaisVelha.value < idade.value && sexo2.checked == true) {
            if(sexo1.checked == true) {
                nomeMaisVelho.value = nome.value;
                idadeMaisVelho.value = idade.value;
            }
            else {
                nomeMaisVelha.value = nome.value;
                idadeMaisVelha.value = idade.value;
            }   
        }
    }

</script>
<body>
<form name = "form1">
Digite o seu nome: <input type = text name = "nome" value = "">
<br><br>
Sexo: Masculino<input type = radio name = "sexo" value = "">
      Feminino<input type = radio name = "sexo" value = "">
<br><br>
Digite a sua idade: <input type = text name = "idade" value = "0">
                    <input type = button name = "classificar" onclick = "execucoes()" value = "Classificar">
<br><br>
Nome do Homem mais velho: <input type = text name = "nomemaisvelho" value = "" disabled>
Idade do Homem mais velho: <input type = text name = "idademaisvelho" value = "" disabled>
<br><br>
Nome da Mulher mais velha: <input type = text name = "nomemaisvelha" value = "" disabled>
Idade da Mulher mais velha: <input type = text name = "idademaisvelha" value = "" disabled>
</body>
</html>
```